# Restrict registration on Meteor to emails from a particular domain

Tags: meteor, registration

This is the closest I've found to an answer on how to restrict sign up on Meteor, but I'd prefer not to have to send every person an invitation: [How to make sign-up invitation only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990550/how-to-make-sign-up-invitation-only/26621540)

So far, this is what I have, but it doesn't work - it doesn't accept any sign ups, even with emails from my college domain. What am I doing wrong - I have struggled with this for hours and I just can't figure it out!

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user) {

    email_regex = new RegExp("/\A[\w+\-.]+@mycollege\.edu\z/i");    
    validemail = false;
    if (email_regex.test(user.emails[0])){
    validemail = true;
    }


      if (validemail)   
        return true;
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You must use an mycollege.edu email to register");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Accounts.config` to create such a rule. It is more convenient than using `Accounts.validateNewUser`:

*both* client and server

```
Accounts.config({
    restrictCreationByEmailDomain: 'college.edu'
});
```

From the docs about [restrictCreationByEmailDomain](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_config):

> If set to a string, only allows new users if the domain part of their
>   email address matches the string. If set to a function, only allows
>   new users if the function returns true. The function is passed the
>   full email address of the proposed new user. Works with password-based
>   sign-in and external services that expose email addresses (Google,
>   Facebook, GitHub). All existing users still can log in after enabling
>   this option